# Target="_blank" not working

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Im develope website with `wordpress`, Im use plugin `Magge Short code`

I want to create a "link" with `shortcode Magee`. 
Here is my current code

```
[ms_social icon_size="25px" title="Instagrame"  target="_blank" icon="fa-instagram" iconcolor="" effect_3d="yes" backgroundcolor="" iconboxedradius="normal" iconlink="https://www.instagram.com/"  class="" id=""][/ms_social]
```

Everything works except `_blank` attribute, even putting `"_blank"`. Can anyone help me fix my code to the link opens in a new tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

plugin :magee-shortcodes/shortcodes/class-social.php

line number: 71 or find this below code and add

### target="_blank"

```
$html=sprintf(' %s <a href="%s" target="_blank" Id="%s" class="fa %s magee-icon  %s %s %s_social_icon_acolor" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="%s"></a>',
            $styles,$iconlink,$id,$icon,$sty3d,$class,$uqid,$title);
```